# Invisible element being hovered when it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, button, navbar, dropdown

I've coded a dropdown login form for my navbar, it works correctly but not entirely, it seems that it also drops down when I hover on the area where the form appears:

[image]

The mouse is just hovering on an area where the dropdown appears but it shoudn't do that, it should drop down when I hover ONLY on "ingresar", how can fix this? Also, I don't want my mouse to look like I can click on the form, it should look normal.

```css
.login-box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu li:hover .login-box {
  opacity: 1;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  color: #efed40;
  text-align: center;
}
.login-box p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.login-box input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.login-box input[type="text"],
.login-box input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.login-box input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #ff267e;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #efed40;
  color: #262626;
}
.login-box a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>INICIO</li>
  <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
  <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE</li>
  <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR
    <div class="login-box">
      <h2>Ingresa tus datos</h2>
      <form>
        <p>CORREO</p>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Escribir e-mail">
        <p>CONTRASEÑA</p>
        <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo">
        <a href="">¿Contraseña olvidada?</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the dropdown to not visible, so no hover event can be applied in it

```
.login-box{
  width: 350px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  /* === NEW ==== */
  visibility: hidden;
}
.menu li:hover .login-box{
  opacity: 1;
  /* === NEW ==== */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**[visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)**